# VBA Error 1004 on pasting Formula in cells VBA

Tags: excel, vba, excel-formula

I'm getting error 1004 when trying to enter a formula using VBA:

```vb
SIOP_sh.Range("E4").FormulaR1C1 = "=IF(SUMIFS(ALCZ_JI_PMD!R3C13:R10002C13,ALCZ_JI_PMD!R3C31:R10002C31,RC3,ALCZ_JI_PMD!R3C11:R10002C11,R1C)=0, IF((SUMIFS(ALCZ_JI_PMD!R3C14:R10002C14,ALCZ_JI_PMD!R3C31:R10002C31,RC3,ALCZ_JI_PMD!R3C11:R10002C11,R1C)=SUMIFS(ALCZ_JI_PMD!R3C23:R10002C23,ALCZ_JI_PMD!R3C31:R10002C31,RC3,ALCZ_JI_PMD!R3C11:R10002C11,R1C)),SUMIFS(ALCZ_JI_PMD!R3C14:R10002C14,ALCZ_JI_PMD!R3C31:R10C3,ALCZ_JI_PMD!R3C11:R10002C11,R1C),SUMIFS(ALCZ_JI_PMD!R3C23:R10002C23,ALCZ_JI_PMD!R3C31:R10002C31,RC3,ALCZ_JI_PMD!R3C11:R10002C11,R1C)),SUMIFS(ALCZ_JI_PMD!R3C13:R10002C13,ALCZ_JI_PMD!R3C31:R10002C31,RC3,ALCZ_JI_PMD!R3C11:R10002C11,R1C))"
```

I used a similar formula before but for this formula above, I'm continuously getting the syntax error. Can you kindly help me with this?

Comment: It looks like you're missing part of the fourth SUMIFS function. Did you record a macro and then try and join the formula up in one row?

Comment: @Rory Yes I recorded the macro and joined them together but the first time I tried to use the exact same formula from macro but it also didn't work.

Comment: Then as I said, your formula is incomplete. When you record a macro with a formula that is too long to fit on one line in the VBE, the recorder actually ends up replacing part of it with the code to break the string onto two lines. You should enter the formula manually in a cell and then get the formula using something like: `debug.print activecell.formular1c1`

Comment: @Rory Yes, you are right. Since VBA breaks the formula, it replaces some part of the formula but I didn't understand the second part of your comment, How do I use `debug.print activecell.formular1c1` to get the correct formula. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Here is your formula blown out with indention marking the missing attribute in your SUMIFS(). You can use a site like [This one](http://excelformulabeautifier.com/) to format your ugly formulas automatically which really helps identifying errors like this.

```
IF(
    SUMIFS(
        ALCZ_JI_PMD!R3C13:R10002C13,
        ALCZ_JI_PMD!R3C31:R10002C31,
        RC3,
        ALCZ_JI_PMD!R3C11:R10002C11,
        R1C
    )=0,
    IF(
        (
            SUMIFS(
                ALCZ_JI_PMD!R3C14:R10002C14,
                ALCZ_JI_PMD!R3C31:R10002C31,
                RC3,
                ALCZ_JI_PMD!R3C11:R10002C11,
                R1C
            )=
            SUMIFS(
                ALCZ_JI_PMD!R3C23:R10002C23,
                ALCZ_JI_PMD!R3C31:R10002C31,
                RC3,
                ALCZ_JI_PMD!R3C11:R10002C11,
                R1C
            )
        ),
        SUMIFS(
            ALCZ_JI_PMD!R3C14:R10002C14,
            ALCZ_JI_PMD!R3C31:R10C3,
            ##################MISSING CONDITION FOR SUMIF HERE##############
            ALCZ_JI_PMD!R3C11:R10002C11,
            R1C
        ),
        SUMIFS(
            ALCZ_JI_PMD!R3C23:R10002C23,
            ALCZ_JI_PMD!R3C31:R10002C31,
            RC3,
            ALCZ_JI_PMD!R3C11:R10002C11,
            R1C
        )
    ),
    SUMIFS(
        ALCZ_JI_PMD!R3C13:R10002C13,
        ALCZ_JI_PMD!R3C31:R10002C31,
        RC3,
        ALCZ_JI_PMD!R3C11:R10002C11,
        R1C
    )
)
```

Assuming that the missing value here is `RC3`, this updated formula should work:

```
=IF(SUMIFS(ALCZ_JI_PMD!R3C13:R10002C13,ALCZ_JI_PMD!R3C31:R10002C31,RC3,ALCZ_JI_PMD!R3C11:R10002C11,R1C)=0,IF((SUMIFS(ALCZ_JI_PMD!R3C14:R10002C14,ALCZ_JI_PMD!R3C31:R10002C31,RC3,ALCZ_JI_PMD!R3C11:R10002C11,R1C)=SUMIFS(ALCZ_JI_PMD!R3C23:R10002C23,ALCZ_JI_PMD!R3C31:R10002C31,RC3,ALCZ_JI_PMD!R3C11:R10002C11,R1C)),SUMIFS(ALCZ_JI_PMD!R3C14:R10002C14,ALCZ_JI_PMD!R3C31:R10C3,RC3,ALCZ_JI_PMD!R3C11:R10002C11,R1C),SUMIFS(ALCZ_JI_PMD!R3C23:R10002C23,ALCZ_JI_PMD!R3C31:R10002C31,RC3,ALCZ_JI_PMD!R3C11:R10002C11,R1C)),SUMIFS(ALCZ_JI_PMD!R3C13:R10002C13,ALCZ_JI_PMD!R3C31:R10002C31,RC3,ALCZ_JI_PMD!R3C11:R10002C11,R1C))
```

Comment: Thank you for your explanation it worked. Do you know a way to prevent VBA from replacing part of my formula when I record it or any other way of copy-pasting excel formula into VBA?